# 3 small holes on a sphere

Tags: mesh

I've been trying for many days to make 3 small holes on a sphere without distorting it with a Subsurf modifier, i tried with shrinkwrap projecting, with hexagons, triangles, ngongs, booleans, to-sphere, there's something beyond my understanding :D
I would appreciate any help. thank you! 
[image]

[image]

Comment: You cannot do it with subsurf without distorting. You can have a boolean after the subsurf or a shrinkwrap after the subsurf, but not before it. Else it is only approximation and you can make the distortion smaller to the point it is no longer noticeable, but it'll still be there. Corrective displacement is also a way.

Comment: These videos from cgcookie might probably help: https://youtu.be/salpctjEdAA https://youtu.be/RGQgqlVq_Cg

Comment: @AshutoshBudhdeo Yup! I already tried that one but it only works with large holes not with many small ones. thanks though!

Answer (score 3):

I began with a cube that I subdivided smooth several times. And actually I ended up with a sort of UV Sphere. But anyway you could include the 6 holes part anywhere in a smoothed cube, as shown with the second sphere.

Note that in my modifiers stack I've used a **Mirror**, then a **Subsurf**, then a **Shrinkrwrap**.

The *Target* of the *Shrinkwrap* is also a smooth subdivided cube (or UV Sphere),as big as my object. It allows my object to nicely stick to a spherical shape. In my screenshot I made it invisible, of course.

[image]

Comment: is there any reason you placed the holes on the "pole" of the sphere?
Thanks to everyone I'll give it a try and I'll post the result

Comment: no, no reason, actually I just ended up with a kind of UV Sphere because it's lower in quads, but as I said you can put your 3 holes wherever you want, see my edit